# How can upload an Image from camera and restricted upload image from gallery in WebView

Tags: camera, android-webview, webview2

WebView in this app opens a page with upload button after call open camera.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUAxJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT20e.png)

I using LIB camera JS but it still show gallery
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8In7c.png)

How can I restricted  image from gallery in WebView?

Tks all

How can I restricted  image from gallery in WebView?

Tks all